# How can I substitute constants into this set of equations? (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to solve this set of trig equations (I'm not exactly sure if the syntax looks correct):

```
Solve[Tan[(delta + beta)/2] == nz*Tan[theta/2] && 
  ny*Tan[(delta - beta)/2] == nx && 
  Cos[(delta + beta)/2]*Cos[gamma/2] == Cos[theta/2], {delta, beta, 
  gamma}, Reals]
```

The goal is to solve for `delta, beta` and `gamma`. I want to substitute different values of `nx,ny,nz,theta` into these equations and get the solutions. How can I substitute those values in there? Thanks:)

Comment: Try `sub={nx->.1,ny->.2,nz->.4,theta->.3};
Solve[{...yourequations...}/.sub,{delta,beta,gamma},Reals]` and see if that works for you.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the comment! It shows me something like `delta -> ConditionalExpression[0.524028 + 3.14159 C[1] + 3.14159 C[2], (C[1] | C[2] | C[3]) \[Element] Integers]`. What that means?

Comment: So that means that delta is going to be replaced by that expression if and only if C[1] or C[2] or C[3] is an integer and it can't tell whether that is true or not. I am guessing that means your substitution turned your trig equations into something that are only valid if some conditions are true.

Comment: @Bill Thanks so much!